# Trying to Create a new Azure VM using a Snapshot of a managed disk with Ansible

Tags: azure, deployment, ansible, devops, clone

I am trying to be able to deploy multiple machines using a GOLD vm snapshot through ansible. I need it to be like this:

```
- name: Creating Virtual Machine as requested.
  azure_rm_virtualmachine:
    resource_group: "{{ virtualMachineRG }}"
    name: "{{ virtualMachineName }}"
    vm_size: "{{ virtualMachineSize }}"
    location: "{{ location }}"
    managed_disk_type: "{{ managed_Disk_Type }}"
    storage_account: "{{ storageAccount }}"
    os_type: "{{ os_type }}"
    image: "{{image}}"
    os_disk_size_gb: "{{ os_disk_size_gb }}"
    admin_username: "{{ adminUsername }}"
    admin_password: "{{ adminPassword }}"
    network_interfaces: "{{ virtualMachineName }}-nic"
```

I need the IMAGE or the entire disk to work similarly to creating a snapshot then creating a VM off the snapshot OR Create a clone of a managed disk and using that instead of the basic IMAGE of windows 10. This would be like having a snapshot that needs the same thing for 10 different VMs based on the request so its not the image that I would need but the GOLD Snapshot in place of the image which has operating system and everything installed. Is this doable? I have tried everything I can find through just searches and ansible documentation. This will deploy a new VM from the snapshot of the GOLD managed disk and this gets updated regularly and is set to the machine that controls the GOLD snapshot.